# Hilt - how can I run code in "init" block that executes injected object's method

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to integrate Hilt in my existing Android app. I've come to a problem where I have some initialisation code inside "init" block of Kotlin class. Here is example code that demonstrates the issue:

```
interface ITest1 {
    fun doSomething()
}

interface ITest2 {
    fun doSomethingElse()
}

class Test1 @Inject constructor(): ITest1 {

    override fun doSomething() {
        println("Something")
    }
}
    
class Test2 @Inject constructor(): ITest2 {

    @Inject
    lateinit var test1: ITest1

    override fun doSomethingElse() {
        println("Something else ")
    }

    init {
        test1.doSomething()
    }
}

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object Dependencies {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideTest1(test1: Test1): ITest1 {
        return test1
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideTest2(test2: Test2): ITest2 {
        return test2
    }
}
```

This code crashes: `Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property test1 has not been initialized`

As I've read about Hilt/Dagger, "test1" will be injected after init/constructor is executed.

I found a workaround for this - I can define my own init method and call it in @Module when I construct "test2", but I wonder is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: For injection, I think you should have a start point in your application. For instance, A fragment or Activity. Then you should provide these objects in the related fragment's module. Then, you need to extend DaggerActivity or fragment, Or you can manually call `AndroidInjector.inject()` (I can't remember the exact function call) at the onAttach() method in the fragment. After these steps, you can inject anything into your Impl class

Comment: That is not an option for me, in project I'm working on I have different modules, some are plain kotlin classes which don't have access to any UI.

Answer (score 1):

You could just pass it through the constructor. So your `Test2` would become:

```
class Test2 @Inject constructor(val test1: ITest1): ITest2
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer.

Currently I have DI done via constructor arguments and I would like to convert to Hilt and property injections (as it makes code maintaining easier). If I would need to use DI via constructor arguments then I don't have a need to use Hilt. 

Comment: @IvanŠkugor, constructor injection is easier to mock in tests.
ref to docs: https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-testing#unit-tests.